# WSO2 ESB Mediation Retrieve user attributes (claims) in inSequence

Tags: json, wso2, wso2-api-manager, wso2-esb

I have published API in API Publisher. That API have POST method `confirm`, which retrieves JSON data with such parameters: userUUID, appName, version. In API Publisher this API takes only two parameters: appName and version.

I don't want to send userUUID from client, but I want to retrieve userUUID from accessToken (it is in user claims) in inSequence and add it to sended JSON as new parameter and then send it all to backend.

Is it possible? Maybe I can retrieve at least user email from accessToken?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found workaround with getting user info from https://localhost:9443/oauth2/userinfo?schema=openid

First of all, change value `RemoveOAuthHeadersFromOutMessage` in `OAuthConfigurations` in file `[WSO2_AM]/repository/conf/api-manager.xml`

Secondly, user claims, that are getting from `https://localhost:9443/oauth2/userinfo?schema=openid` should be configured in WSO2 API Manager Carbon Server in Service Providers.

Algorithm:

1. Copy request body to property `body_of_zero_call`
2. Copy request target REST API method to property `urlPostfixZero`
3. Set value `?schema=openid` as request target REST API method
4. Call https://localhost:9443/oauth2/userinfo?schema=openid to get user info
5. Check reponse code: if 200, then going through, else return code 500 with message `{ "status": "Can't get user info"}`
6. Copy interesting info (in my case `user_uuid`) from response body to property `user_uuid_first_call`
7. Copy source request body from property `body_of_zero_call` to body
8. Copy source request target REST API method from property `urlPostfixZero` to request target REST API method
9. Add element `userUUID` to request body
10. Fill element `userUUID` in body with value from property `user_uuid_first_call`
11. Call target URL with changed body and target REST API method
12. Respond

Mediator:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<sequence xmlns="http://ws.apache.org/ns/synapse" name="token_to_user_uuid" trace="disable">
   <!-- 1 -->
   <enrich>
      <source clone="true" type="body" />
      <target action="child" property="body_of_zero_call" type="property" />
   </enrich>
   <!-- 2 -->
   <property expression="$axis2:REST_URL_POSTFIX" name="urlPostfixZero" scope="default" type="STRING" />
   <!-- 3 -->
   <property name="REST_URL_POSTFIX" scope="axis2" type="STRING" value="?schema=openid" />
   <!-- 4 -->
   <call blocking="true">
      <endpoint>
         <http method="get" trace="disable" uri-template="https://localhost:9443/oauth2/userinfo" />
      </endpoint>
   </call>
   <!-- 5 -->
   <filter regex="200" source="get-property('axis2', 'HTTP_SC')">
      <then>
         <!-- 6 -->
         <property expression="$body//jsonObject//user_uuid" name="user_uuid_first_call" scope="default" type="STRING" />
         <!-- 7 -->
         <enrich>
            <source clone="true" property="body_of_zero_call" type="property" />
            <target type="body" />
         </enrich>
         <!-- 8 -->
         <property expression="get-property('urlPostfixZero')" name="REST_URL_POSTFIX" scope="axis2" type="STRING" />
         <!-- 9 -->
         <enrich>
            <source clone="true" type="inline">
               <userUUID xmlns="" />
            </source>
            <target action="child" xpath="$body//jsonObject" />
         </enrich>
         <!-- 10 -->
         <enrich>
            <source clone="true" property="user_uuid_first_call" type="property" />
            <target xpath="$body//jsonObject//userUUID" />
         </enrich>
         <!-- 11 -->
         <call blocking="true">
            <endpoint>
               <http method="post" trace="disable" uri-template="https://localhost:9444/customAuth/services/regulations" />
            </endpoint>
         </call>
         <!-- 12 -->
         <respond />
      </then>
      <else>
         <property name="HTTP_SC" scope="axis2" type="STRING" value="500" />
         <payloadFactory media-type="json">
            <format>{ "status": "Can't get user info"}</format>
            <args />
         </payloadFactory>
         <respond />
      </else>
   </filter>
</sequence>
```

Answer (score 1):

I see two ways to pass user information to the backend.

- One is the JWT token. In the api-manager.xml you can enable the JWT token generation with the claim retriever. The JWT token will be sent to the backend service as an HTTP header
- in the sequence you can call one of the admin services ( see https://docs.wso2.com/display/AM210/WSO2+Admin+Services ) for to get assigned user and application

see https://localhost:9443/services/OAuth2TokenValidationService?wsdl and the **validate** or **buildIntrospectionResponse** operation

I hope it helped

Comment: Very useful answer. Could you please show me, how to call admin services in the sequence? Maybe I can also call https://localhost:9443/oauth2/userinfo?schema=openid in sequence?